# Facebook game Scores iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, leaderboard

I'm making a new game right now where you can save your highscore, but I wobdered if I could implement a Facebook leaderboard. So the user could see their friend and see what their highscores are. Is this possible? Well, I saw this in different apps like Subway surfers from kiloo and 2048 from ketchapp. I didn't code anything because I don't how to do it. And I searched the facebook developer page and they said you have to do it with the graph API with scores or something. However, Hope you guys can help me out.

Best Regards.

Tom de Ruiter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is probably too broad to really get a good answer. Questions where you're asking for opinions are considered off-topic; please read the guidelines for more information on what constitutes a good question. The general model is that you should try out an approach on your own, and if you really get stuck, ask a targeted question here that includes a snippet of code, what you've tried, and the exact problem you're running into.

Answer (score 1):

There's the Facebook Scores API, the documentation is at this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/

The downside is that Facebook will only store 1 score for a player, when you update it, you won't be able to see any previous scores (Of course, unless you set your own servers to do the job).

Also, there's no easy recipe to work with the Graph API, you just have to follow a few tutorials and you'll be in good shape to work with scores.